# How does the Pocket Beagle assign 192.168.7.2 to itself and 192.168.7.1 to the computer it is connected to via USB?

Tags: embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I understand that it is running some kind of local `DHCP` server but specifically what is the Pocket Beagle/Beagle Bone Black running that allows it to allocate the address `192.168.7.2` to itself and `192.168.7.1` to the computer which it is connected to? And if I wanted to change those addresses to something else how would I be able to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from BeagleBoard.org:

> If connected via USB, a network adapter should show up on your
> computer. Your Beagle should be running a DHCP server that will
> provide your computer with an IP address of either 192.168.7.1 or
> 192.168.6.1, depending on the type of USB network adapter supported by your computer's operating system. Your Beagle will reserve 192.168.7.2
> or 192.168.6.2 for itself.
>
> If your Beagle includes WiFi, an access point called "BeagleBone-XXXX"
> where "XXXX" varies between boards. The access point password defaults
> to "BeagleBone". Your Beagle should be running a DHCP server that will
> provide your computer with an IP address in the 192.168.8.x range and
> reserve 192.168.8.1 for itself.

On my BeagleBone Blue with Debian Buster I found the configurations in the `/etc/dnsmasq.d/SoftAp0` file:

[image]

And this is the service:

[image]